# Xcode 9 : Archiving framework creating alias inside framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

Archiving framework through script creating an alias of the framework. I’m working on a project which has other custom frameworks. Main target has a scheme which is dependent on multiple frameworks. Attached image for better understanding.

[image]

Everything is running fine in debug mode, each framework is being built & created properly but when I try to archive project the archive process passes but frameworks itself contains alias/shortcuts.

[image]
[image]

For archiving I used script like -
[image]

I tried multiple ways to build, clean, delete derived data, changed Optimization Level etc. 
What is the possible solution for the case?

Comment: I've encountered a similar issue with symlinks/aliases when copying frameworks during a build phase. I was able to fix it by replacing `cp -R` with the `ditto` command. For example: `ditto MyFramework.framework <targetDir>/MyFramework.framework` https://ss64.com/osx/ditto.html